# How do you calculate days between dates in SharePoint 2016 list without adding 1, Including the original date, and keeping the blanks?

Tags: splistitem

I have a form that a user is filling out by using SharePoint Columns. There are a varied amount of dates that they get to choose from. The form will take a start date and an end date and count the total number of days between them.

For example Start Date: `4/2/18  End Date: 4/9/18 is a total of 8 days.`

If I use the following code in SP 2016:`=DATEDIF([Start Date],[End Date]+1,"D")`

The formula will work. However, it adds 1 whenever there are no dates entered. I need to account for all the zeros/blanks and create a report out of that. So I need to see the blanks/zeros.

What formula can I use that just counts the days without having to add 1 to include the date?

I've tried: =DAYS(End Date,Start Date) and this returns #NUM. Can anyone help?

Comment: hi please what if you want the end date to be automatically populated based on the day input is filled in..for example.End date will be generated automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using an `IF` Function to check if the Start Date has a value before doing your calculation. This way you can return no value if there are no dates selected.

It should look something like this:

`=IF(ISBLANK([Start Date]),"",DATEDIF([Start Date],[End Date]+1,"D"))`

Additionally, you can add another `ISBLANK` check for the End Date so that it will only calculate if both Start and End Dates have been selected. That would look something like this:

`=IF(ISBLANK([Start Date]),"",IF(ISBLANK([End Date]),"",DATEDIF([Start Date],[End Date]+1,"D")))`

Comment: Thank you Vanblart! I've tried your first suggestion: =IF(ISBLANK([Start Date]),"",DATEDIF([Start Date],[End Date]+1,"D")) and it works well.

Comment: I confirm that I now tried both solutions and they work well. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Please try use the following formula, if either any date is blank will return blank

```
=IF(OR(date1="",date2=""),"",DATEDIF(date1,date2 +1,"d"))
```

Comment: A. Saeed, since you took the time out of your day to respond to my question. I tried your solution out as well and it worked. Thank you!

Comment: @Sun you're welcome , glad to help :) , please mark either solutions which works for you as an answer so your question be marked as answered.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: @Sun select the check mark beside the answer , only one answer can be marked

Comment: A. Saeed, can you help me calculate the average? I posted another question where I used your logic. But I think I'm doing something wrong.